# Android Google Cloude Messaging Error

Tags: android

I am working on sending notifications using GCM I have include the  
`import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging`
But  I am getting an error in the eclipse 
**The import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging cannot be resolved**
 But I have included the gcm.jar file , gcm-server-1.0.2.jar  and google-play-services_lib.jar still I am getting the same error.

I have tried code is:

```
package com.example.gcm;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends IntentService {

    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    public static final String TAG = "GCMNotificationIntentService";

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
                        + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                    .equals(messageType)) {

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG,
                            "Working... " + (i + 1) + "/5 @ "
                                    + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }

                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

                sendNotification("Message Received from Google GCM Server: "
                        + extras.get(Config.MESSAGE_KEY));
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
```

pls guys can you please help me

Thanks

Comment: Keep only play service jar file and remove other jar files, also add your jar files to build path in your eclipse. Because play service bundled with GCM classes.

Comment: i have done the same but i am getting the error@Silvans

Comment: what error are you getting, can you please put error or screen shot of error here

Comment: The import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging cannot be resolved @Silvans Solanki

Comment: remove that line from the class and import class which is in the play service jar and it will resolved your issue.

Comment: we have some dependent code is there   can u pls see the above code that lines will come as errors like   GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
(with error like "GoogleCloudMessaging cannot be resolved to a type") and some other lines also

Comment: Are you sending notification using GCM or you try to received push using GCM and show push notification in the notification bar?

Comment: yes i am sending notification using GCM  @Silvans Solanki

Comment: you are not sending notification, you are showing notification in your mobile which is received with Push Notification, right?